# Showing order statistic is sufficient

Tags: statistics, sufficient-statistics

Suppose the model $P_θ$ is the class of all continuous distributions; this is called a ‘nonparametric family’, where the unknown parameter $θ$ is the whole distribution function. Let $x_1,...,x_n$ be an iid sample from $P_θ$. Show that the order statistics are sufficient for $P_θ$.

My thinking:
given $\theta$ is the whole distribution function of order statistics we have:
$$F_{\Theta_{(r)}}(\theta) = \sum_{j=r}^n\binom{n}{j}F_{\Theta}(\theta)^j(1-F_{\Theta}(\theta))^{n-j}$$

and by the factorisation theorem we have:
$$\left\{F_{\Theta}(\theta)^j(1-F_{\Theta}(\theta))^{n-j}\right\}\left\{\sum_{j=r}^n\binom{n}{j}\right\}$$

such that $p_{\theta}(x) = g(t(x), \theta)h(x)$ where $h(x)$ is free of $\theta$. In this case, we have that for the order statistics $\left\{F_{\Theta}(\theta)^j(1-F_{\Theta}(\theta))^{n-j}\right\}$ is sufficient?

On another note: what is meant by $P_{\theta}$ is the "class"?

Comment: The parametric model should depend on $x$, not only $\theta$

Comment: Intuitively, the full sample is always sufficient, and since they are i.i.d. they are exchangeable and so the order statistics are sufficient.

Comment: @Henry I'm trying to find a statistics proof with mathematical notation. For example, if we let $X_1 ... X_n$ be iid from a pdf, where we are unable to specify any more information about the pdf. It then follows that the sample density is given by $f(x) = \prod_{i=1}^nf(x_i) = \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i)$ where $x_i \le \cdots \le x_n$ are the order statistics. By the conditional sufficient statistic, for every x in the sample space the ratio $\frac{p(x|\theta)}{q(T(x)|\theta)}$ is a constant as a function of $\theta$